# How to solve the RootCA certification warning while recording jmeter script for mobile device?

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am recording the jmeter script for mobile application, while starting script it shows Root CA certification warning.So how can i solve this warning error?

if i ignore this & recording the script is fine but i want to resolve the certification error so is there any need to install the certification file on mobile device?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error. It's a warning!!! This is required to allow JMeter to decrypt HTTPS traffic while doing the recording of protected websites.

You can use [BlazeMeter Recorder (Mobile Recorder)](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Recorder-Mobile-Recorder-).

Answer (score 0):

(jmetr 3.0)its come after jmeter.batch running.Please follow belwo steps.
click ok and go on bin directory in jmeter.open "ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA" and click install certification.then next > place all certificates and browse and choose Trusted Root first menu.
Then ok >next > ok.
Recording script on .